# Ruby uniq with extra condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, uniq

I have an array of ActiveRecord objects where Object.word is a string.

I know that

```
array.uniq{|s| s.word}
```

will return the objects with unique :word values.

I also want to make an extra condition (using uniq if possible) so that no word is one character away from another: specifically, I don't want to return objects with both the words "know" and "knows", or "weigh" and "weighs" but only to choose one of them.

Is there a neat, intuitive way to achieve this?

Comment: In both your examples, one of the words you want to get rid of is always the other word with "s" on the end.  Is that your actual requirements?   Or, does it apply to any single-character difference?  For example if your input is `["foo", "bar", "too", "bat"]`, what would you want to get back?

Comment: And what about `["bat", "bet", "bit", "sit", "sat", "set"]`?

Comment: Ideally it would return only word with a unique lemma, but as am on a tight deadline, I'm not going there right now :) So my short term fix is to exclude third person present tense of the word.

Comment: Sorry, but i barely scraped a pass in english language at school and so don't know what you mean.  Can you please **very clearly** specify what output you would want for each of my input examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use reject to reject some elements depend on some conditions for example:

```
 [1,2,3].reject {|a| a > 1}  # [1]
```

Comment: Something like  `array.reject{|a| array.include?(a+'s')}` ?

Comment: Yes, if that's is your condition.

Comment: Something like that, but you'll have to figure out the algorithm for determining the "closeness" of the word. That's really a separate question from how to inject a conditional into selecting items.

Comment: @jefflunt I am using [Fuzzy String Matching](https://github.com/kiyoka/fuzzy-string-match)  for that at present.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `singularize` in Rails to get the singular value of the word, and still use your `uniq` code:

```
array.uniq{|s| s.word.singularize}


[2] pry(main)> ["test", "tests", "word", "words", "entity", "entities"].uniq{|s| s.singularize}
=> ["test", "word", "entity"]
```

Comment: Nice. But am assuming that doesn't work with verbs too.

Comment: Can you give an example of plural verb in english?

Comment: I mean differentiating between "know" and "knows" - base present form and 3rd person present form.

Comment: You want to exclude plural words, but keep verbs if they have different form?
["test", "tests", "know", "knows"].magic_method == ["test", "know", "knows"]